# Remove or change the default description of exposed properties

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-app-builder

I am currently trying to add a description/tooltip to an exposed property of my component, so that information on how to properly fill in data is readily available, when the component is added via the Lightning App Builder. The problem I run into however, is that there is a default description, which will be displayed whether or not I add a description inside the components configuration file or not.

The default description reads:

> This property supports using an expression to define its custom label. The correct format is {!$Label.customLabelName}.

As can be seen on this screenshot:
[image]

As for my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>58.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordPage">
            <property name="Fields" type="String" description="Ideally, this would be the only sentence being rendered"/>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Last but not least, the way the tooltip looks, when I do not add the description attribute:
[image]